# PHP Geolocation API

Tags: php, api, geolocation

I need to show specific content in my page depending of user location.
My application will be similar to http://www.yelp.com/. I want at the homepage to show the business from the city where the user is located. (by checking it´s ip address).

Does anybody know any good PHP geolication api?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+geolocation+api

Comment: What is the question? A good php geolocation API or to show specific content despending?

Comment: [Please do your homework before asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) and if you did, point out why none of the many duplicates help solving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Geo IP](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip) PECL package and [Net_GeoIP](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_GeoIP) PEAR package both provide an interface to the maxmind location database, which is a free API to get you country (and some city) level details based upon IP. I believe they have a system where you can pay to get more detail.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.maxmind.com/app/php

MaxMind offers both commercial and free databases to use with that API.

Answer (score 1):

I have used GeoIp before, as I rembember, its free, but you can purchase a non-free version. I don't know if that's a requirement.
It basically translates an IP to the country code.