# Is there a paid of free service that will allow accurate geo-location lookups of IP addresses?

Tags: geolocation, location, ip, lookup

I'm looking for something that will give an exact address, so the solution will probably have to be paid for, as access to the ISP is required to get exact location.

It's for business use, so... nothing creepy going on here, just fyi

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Geolocation API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449860/php-geolocation-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even the police cannot access this info without the correct warrants, let alone any normal citizen.

It would be a HUGE privacy violation if this was possible, so I guess the answer is:

It does not exist.